# Who made this violent speech in the documentary De Nuremberg à Nuremberg?

Tags: germany, nazism

In F. Rossif's documentary [De Nuremberg à Nuremberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Nuremberg_%C3%A0_Nuremberg) at some point you can hear a pretty violent and aggressive speech ([begins at 25:19](http://dailymotion.com/video/x5ae04t) and ends up at 25:44) from which I could hardly understand things like:

> wir holen den Teufel aus der Hölle...
>   und Stalin und London und Moskow und Washington...
>   der Juda wir fallen...
>   der Deutsche mag den Jude nicht - der Jude den Deutsche nicht...
>   Feudalismus der Juden weg !

These words and same images are displayed twice throughout the documentary. The second instance is to be found [in the second part of that documentary](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xwe0at)  (Starts at 20:04).

I've been wondering for long who made this speech: someone has an idea ? And about the date of the recording ?

Comment: "Juda wird fallen"... "der Deutsche mag den Juden nicht - der Jude den Deutschen nicht, infolgedessen muss der Jude weg". Seems like that could be about *any* of Hitlers or Goebbels speeches. Even if we had a perfectly indexed archive, I doubt you would get a single hit. You'd probably get a few dozen.

Comment: This extreme outspoken virulence sounds like it could have been Julius Streicher. Voice also sounds more like him, certainly more like Hitler and while somewhat similar, Goebbels had a different quite distinct diction.

Comment: @Marakai I agree that neither Hitler ([but](https://www.gedenkstaettenforum.de/nc/gedenkstaetten-rundbrief/rundbrief/news/besprechungen_von_cd_rom_zum_themenkomplex_nationalsozialismus-2/)!) nor Goebbels really come to mind, more Streicher and [*Ley*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTHS8-AiT8o).

Comment: @nvoigt And really, the example *is* a mix of three speakers, both using very 'popular' formulations.

Comment: @LangLangC  good call on Ley. Streicher had a fairly pronounced Franconian accent which I can't make out here. Though the audio quality makes that hard one way or the other.

Answer (score 5):

Nobody.

And everyone.

This is an *audio-illustration* of the common nazi rhetoric. Not *a* particular speech, more a pastiche made from original recordings. If you listen closely you will identify al least three distinct voices from at least three different speakers. As this is a montage, you will not find "the one guy that made this speech". Also compare this with the French narration that precedes these samples: That "this violent antisemitism became the only form of officially authorised pornography in the Third Reich."

This is also recognisable in the speeches ductus and diction. Search for example through [some of Hitler's speeche](http://www.worldfuturefund.org/wffmaster/Reading/Hitler%20Speeches/Hitler%20Key%20Speeches%20Index.htm)s searching for the string "jude": multiple hits. Search for "juda": zero hits. Likewise for *Mein Kampf:* just one time *Judaslohn.* He liked the "Juden" and "Judentum" – words – but not Juda.

Likewise, a search for the whole line of words as identifiable so far from the one excerpt in the question now leads right back to this question.

Therefore I would like to offer the following suggestion.

We hear little snippets of nazi speeches. Those are most likely typical, that is from Adolf Hitler, [Joseph Goebbels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Goebbels), [Julius Streicher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Streicher), [Hermann Göring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_G%C3%B6ring), [and Robert Ley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Ley). Those were the most violent speakers in general, but Streicher and Ley in particular stand out as really screaming hysterically when it came to their antisemitic convictions.

From a rough guess I'd sort the "Amerika"-part to Goebbels, the "Jude mag den"-part to perhaps Hitler (An old review for a an educational CDROM implies that this part, only those few words, and as written, no audio to compare –  might be from from Hitler: ["»Der Deutsche mag den Juden nicht, der Jude den Deutschen nicht […]«"](https://www.gedenkstaettenforum.de/nc/gedenkstaetten-rundbrief/rundbrief/news/besprechungen_von_cd_rom_zum_themenkomplex_nationalsozialismus-2/). Note that the very next part ("…muss der Jude weg") is not in that link and also sounds different in the montage). "Juda muss fallen"-part seems to be very close to the words of Ley, for example in his [Siemens-Schulungsappell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTHS8-AiT8o) from 1942 ([transcript by Siemens](https://www.vip-siemens.de/Daten/Siemens-Mitteilung1942.pdf)).

The assignment of identified voices to parts is explicitly my own, probably incorrect sloppy, guesswork. The audio quality of the video in question is bad even in the narrated modern parts. But it seems really clear in using more than one snippet, cut tightly together.

---

What I would transcribe from what is heard by my ears on the first mention of it  ([2e Guerre Mondiale - De Nuremberg a Nuremberg Chapitre 1 #1](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5ae04t) begins at 25:19 and ends up at 25:44):

> […?] Teufel aus der Hölle… [und Stalin und London und Moskau und Washington…??] denn Juda, Juda wird fallen… auf, auf mit euch Juden nach Amerika, [da wo ihr?] hingehört… der Deutsche mag den Juden nicht - der Jude den Deutsche nicht, infolgedessen muss der Jude weg!

But the second example is different as well: [De Nuremberg à Nuremberg - 2 de 3 - partie 2 de 2 ( Starts at 20:04)](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/xwe0at)

> und wenn es mit Ihnen wäre… mit Ihnen wäre wir holen den Teufel aus der Hölle, und Stalin, und Moskau und London,  und Washington – sie werden fallen! Denn Juda, Juda wird fallen… Auf, auf mit euch Juden nach Amerika. In das letze [den letzten Sumpf?…?] da wo ihr hingehört. … Der Deutsche mag den Juden nicht, der Jude mag den Deutschen nicht, infolgedessen muss der Jude weg!

Note the editing error in this part, it loops the first part!

All ldots seem to indicate a break in the flow of speech –– and a change in speaker.

Distinct voice change seem to be before the "Amerika" speech (my guess: Ley). Then seems to follow the Rhenish pronunciation of Amerika that sounds like Goebbels (he really loved "Amerika", and envied it). The doubling of "auf" seems also a typical element of his style and the possibility of emigration hinted at in this part indicates an early date for this speech. Then "der Jude mag" might be indeed be Hitler himself, but the "muss weg" part *is* different from his usual screams and just too hysterical, even for that man.

As this is quite tiring to listen to repeatedly and no freely available or searchable text on the net will incorporate all parts of this pastiche in one go anyway, I'll close this with the following guess: we can hear Ley, Goebbels and Hitler assembled together. If we can trust the documentary the parts of these speeches seem to be  dated at shortly around the November 9, 1938 date, although I suspect that the first Ley-part might be even later.

Comment: Partially correct. A search for "der Deutsche mag den Juden nicht, der Jude den Deutschen nicht“ does give a result to a German audio archive. But unfortunately without identifying the speaker.

Comment: @Marakai Well, it is only a partial answer… but got a link for your find?

Comment: https://www.gedenkstaettenforum.de/nc/gedenkstaetten-rundbrief/rundbrief/news/besprechungen_von_cd_rom_zum_themenkomplex_nationalsozialismus-2/

Comment: @Marakai I linked to that already below the Q, and the text there implies that *they* identifies AH with it. But is there really any audio behind that link? I read that as an old Win3.1 CDrom review, text-only review that is?

Comment: Ah I missed that. Yeah I noticed the IMHO false identification of Hitler